# flowplayer start / stop on loading external source

Tags: external, playback, flowplayer

I have a video shown in flowplayer from an external provider and I only have this few lines to embed the vidoe to ma page:

```
<script src="http://domain.com/live/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://domain.com/live/js/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://domain.com/live/js/flowplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://domain.com/live/js/mi/vod.de.php?id=10857"></script>
```

The player starts right when the page is loaded.

This is the div for the player:

```
<div id="panes">
    <a id="player" style="display:block;width:624px;height:344px;"></a>
 </div>
```

How can I stop, pause and play the video manually?
How can I find out how I can "talk" to the player in order to stop/play the video?

I tried:

```
$f('player', '??', {
```

But how do I know the path to the swf file?

Please help!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Good question! I am also want to know how to start it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use last version of the [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/download/).
2. Use this format to start Flowplayer

( Some discussion u can find here https://github.com/flowplayer/flowplayer/issues/19 )

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>     try {         
>        flowplayer().load([{ mp4: "http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4" }]);
>     } catch (e) {
>                     alert(e.message);
>                 }
>
>     });
> ```